# handling responseBody of Msxml2.XMLhttps

Tags: javascript, vbscript, wsh

Hi i am trying to download a file by a .jse file

```
function download(link, file) {
    var d = WScript.CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLhttp");
    d.open("GET", link, false);
    d.send(null);
    var c = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
    with(c) return Mode = 3, Type = 1, Open(), Write(d["responseBody"]), SaveToFile(file, 2), Close(), file
}
```

it works but i dont want to write to file the first 100 bytes i received so i am trying to do like this

```
Write(d["responseBody"].slice(100))
```

or

```
Write(d["responseBody"].substring(100))
```

but it doesnt work i cant do anything with `d["responseBody"]`

also i cant get size of `responseBody` too

```
WScript.Echo(d["responseBody"].length);
```

there is exactly nothing i can do with `responseBody` why? how can i delete first 100 bytes?

Comment: solved by using 2 different stream by ADODB.Stream

Comment: you must be a single-line fetish :) this also works. `with(c) return Mode = 3, Type = 1, Open(), Write(d.responseBody), Position > 100 ? position = 100 : position = position, SetEos(), SaveToFile(file, 2), Close()`